# Including an image into a label

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I'm having a label defined as below:

```
QLabel* label_min;
label_min = new QLabel(this);
label_min->setGeometry(QRect(10, 20, 640, 480));
```

I'm also having a cv::Mat image as:

```
cv::Mat Mat_dst;
```

I didn't find a way to include that image into the label above.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first convert cv::Mat to a QImage (which is not trivial as it might seem), and then convert that QImage to QPixmap and use setPixmap function.

Converting a cv::Mat image to QImage, as I said, is not trivial. It depends on what is your image type (RGB or monochrome or ...) and the lifetime of the cv::Mat object if making a deep copy of the cv::Mat image to QImage is expensive for you.

```
cv::Mat cvImg; // your opencv image
QImage img = OpenCV2Qt(cvImg); // Implementation of this function depends on cvImage
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

For converting the cv::Mat to QImage object, since no more information about the type of the image is provided, I believe it is better to see the following posts on stackoverflow:

[how to convert an opencv cv::Mat to qimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage)

[cv::Mat to QImage conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015481/cvmat-to-qimage-conversion)

One last thing to remember is that if you are using RGB images, OpenCV stores their data in BGR order but Qt stores in RGB order; so you either have to call cvtColor(mat, rgb, CV_BGR2RGB) or qimg.rgbSwapped().