# How to convert QImage to opencv Mat

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have searched on the internet but I cannot find a method of converting a `QImage`(or `QPixmap`) to a OpenCV `Mat`. How would I do this?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170485/qimage-to-cvmat-convertion-strange-behaviour)

Comment: @Thrustmaster - not quite a dupe, the issues of stepping only matters going the other way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the QImage will still exist, and you just need to perform a quick operation on it then you can construct a cv::Mat using the QImage memory:

`cv::Mat mat(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC3, (cv::Scalar*)image.scanLine(0));`

This assumes that the QImage is 3-channels, ie RGB888.

If the QImage is going away then you need to copy the data, see [Qimage to cv::Mat convertion strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170485/qimage-to-cvmat-convertion-strange-behaviour).

If QImage is Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied (the preferred format) then you will need to convert each pixel to OpenCV's BGR layout. The cv::cvtcolor() function can convert ARGB to RGB in the latest versions.
Or you can use [QImage::convertToFormat()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) to convert to RGB before copying the data.

Comment: Do I have to loop over every pointer in the image using scanLine?

Comment: @user1576633 no, the QImage is stored consecutively scanLine(), with no arg, points to the start of the image data

Comment: Why not simply clone this mat to another one, if QImage is going away?

Comment: Also, I cannot find scanLine() overloaded with not args at all.

Comment: The way you suggest throw a compilation error that says: *'rows' : is not a member of 'QImage'* and the same for 'cols' and 'scanline'.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated, changing it to ```cv::MatMat mat(img.height(), img.width(), CV_8UC4, (cv::Scalar*)img.scanLine(0));``` works for RGBA8888.

Answer (score 11):

One year after you issued this question there've been great answers on the internet:

- [*Convert between cv::mat and Qimage correctly*](http://qtandopencv.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-convert-between-cvmat-and-qimage.html)
- [*Converting Between cv::Mat and QImage or QPixmap*](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/)

But the way I see it, if you're working with Qt and OpenCV at the same time then type `QImage` is probably **just for displaying**, that case you might want to use `QPixmap` since it's optimized for displaying. So this is what I do:

1. Load image as `cv::Mat`, if you'd like to display the image, convert to `QPixmap` using the non-copy method introduced in the second article.
2. Do your image processing in `cv::Mat`.
3. Any time during the workflow you can call upon something like `Mat2QPixmap()` to get realtime result.
4. Never convert `QPixmap` to `cv::Mat`, there's no sense doing it considering the purpose of each type.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this with Qt 5.11 (and probably some earlier versions):

```
    cv::Mat mat(image.height(), image.width(),CV_8UC3, image.bits());  
    // image.scanline() does not exist, 
    //and height/width is interchanged for a matrix
```

Again the QImage is assumed to be RGB888 (ie QImage::Format_RGB888)

Answer (score 3):

My attempt in OpenCV 3.1+ style code:

```
void qimage_to_mat(const QImage& image, cv::OutputArray out) {

    switch(image.format()) {
        case QImage::Format_Invalid:
        {
            cv::Mat empty;
            empty.copyTo(out);
            break;
        }
        case QImage::Format_RGB32:
        {
            cv::Mat view(image.height(),image.width(),CV_8UC4,(void *)image.constBits(),image.bytesPerLine());
            view.copyTo(out);
            break;
        }
        case QImage::Format_RGB888:
        {
            cv::Mat view(image.height(),image.width(),CV_8UC3,(void *)image.constBits(),image.bytesPerLine());
            cvtColor(view, out, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            QImage conv = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
            cv::Mat view(conv.height(),conv.width(),CV_8UC4,(void *)conv.constBits(),conv.bytesPerLine());
            view.copyTo(out);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void mat_to_qimage(cv::InputArray image, QImage& out)
{
    switch(image.type())
    {
        case CV_8UC4:
        {
            cv::Mat view(image.getMat());
            QImage view2(view.data, view.cols, view.rows, view.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
            out = view2.copy();
            break;
        }
        case CV_8UC3:
        {
            cv::Mat mat;
            cvtColor(image, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA); //COLOR_BGR2RGB doesn't behave so use RGBA
            QImage view(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
            out = view.copy();
            break;
        }
        case CV_8UC1:
        {
            cv::Mat mat;
            cvtColor(image, mat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
            QImage view(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
            out = view.copy();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Image format not supported");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
cv::Mat to_cvmat(QImage img)
{
    img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888, Qt::ColorOnly).rgbSwapped();
    return cv::Mat(img.height(), img.width(), CV_8UC3, img.bits(), img.bytesPerLine()).clone();
}
```