# Canon LiveView: image convertion to OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, edsdk

I'm trying to show LiveView image in real time. I use EDSDK 2.14 + Qt5 + opencv+mingw32 under Windows. I'm not very sophisticated in image processing so now I have the following problem. I use example from Canon EDSDK and all was ok until this part of code:

`//
// Display image
//`

I googled a lot of examples but all of them was written on C# or MFC or VB. Also I found advise to use libjpegTurbo for decompressing image and then showing it using opencv. I tried to use libjpegTurbo but failed to undestand what to do :(. Maybe somebody here have code example of the conversion LiveView stream to opencv Mat or QImage (because I use Qt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Canon EDSDKs example, you may append your EdsStreamRef 'stream' data  with its correct length into a `QByteArray`. Then, use for example the following to parse the raw data from the QByteArray as a JPG into a new QImage:
`QImage my_image = QImage::fromData(limagedata,"JPG");` Once it's in a QImage you can convert it into a OpenCV cv::Mat (see [How to convert QImage to opencv Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886123/how-to-convert-qimage-to-opencv-mat))

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me after following the SAMPLE 10 from the Canon EDSDK Reference. It's a starting point for a more robust solution.

In the downloadEvfData function, I replaced the "Display Image" part by the code bellow:

```
unsigned char *data = NULL;
EdsUInt32 size = 0;
EdsSize coords ;

// get image coordinates
EdsGetPropertyData(evfImage, kEdsPropsID_Evf_CoordinateSystem, 0, sizeof(coords), &coords);

// get buffer pointer and size
EdsGetPointer(stream, (EdsVoid**)&data);
EdsGetLenth(stream, &size);

//
// release stream and evfImage
//

// create mat object
Mat img(coords.height, coords.width, CV_8U, data);
image = imdecode(img, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

I've also changed the function signature:

```
EdsError downloadEvfData(EdsCameraRef camera, Mat& image)
```

And in the main function:

```
Mat image;
namedWindow("main", WINDOW_NORMAL);
startLiveView(camera);
for(;;) {
    dowloadEvfData(camera, image);
    imshow("main", image);
    if (waitkey(10) >= 0);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the format of the liveview-stream.

There must be some kind of delimiter in it and you need then to convert each image and update your QImage with it.

Check out this tutorial for more information: [Canon EDSDK Tutorial in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
QImage img = QImage::fromData(data, length, "JPG");

m_image = QImageToMat(img);

// -----------------------------------------
cv::Mat MainWindow::QImageToMat(QImage& src)
{
     cv::Mat tmp(src.height(),src.width(),CV_8UC4,(uchar*)src.bits(),src.bytesPerLine());
     cv::Mat result = tmp.clone(); 
     return result;
}


// -------------------------
void MainWindow::ShowVideo()
{
    namedWindow("yunhu",WINDOW_NORMAL);
    while(1)
    {
        requestLiveViewImage();
        if(m_image.data != NULL)
        {
            imshow("yunhu", m_image);
            cvWaitKey(50);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanations. As is, your answer has been flagged as "low quality"