# How to transfer the image drawn using Qt Paint Application to Mat openCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have created a drawing application using Qt. Now, I whatever I draw, I need to process the image. So, I want to transfer the drawn image to Mat in openCV. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886123/how-to-convert-qimage-to-opencv-mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote code snippet for transfering screnshot to `cv::Mat`, but I hope that you understand main idea, which conversation you should do.

```
    QPixmap win = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
    QImage scr = win.toImage().scaled(640,480);
    QImage screen = scr.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
    cv::Mat tmp(screen.height(),screen.width(),CV_8UC3,(uchar*)screen.bits(),screen.bytesPerLine());
    cvtColor(tmp, tmp,CV_BGR2RGB);
```

Now `cv::Mat` contains this image.

Example:

```
QPixmap okno = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
QImage scr = okno.toImage().scaled(640,480);
QImage screen = scr.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
cv::Mat tmp(screen.height(),screen.width(),CV_8UC3,(uchar*)screen.bits(),screen.bytesPerLine());
cvtColor(tmp, tmp,CV_BGR2RGB);
cv::namedWindow("d");
cv::imshow("d",tmp);
```

`imshow` shows `cv::Mat` properly.

Comment: Getting error, undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)',
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'

Comment: @user3747190 it isn't problem with my example code, something wrong with your project and all links given by google said that it is problem with linking libraries.